# Does Websocket connection affect the connection pool on server?

Tags: java, http, tomcat, websocket

I plan to transfer my server from REST to websockets. The onnection pool on server allows 200 connections, for example. If I start to use websockets I think the server pool will be exhausted very fast because websocket keeps the connection and it can't return it to the pool. Or probably I don't enough understand how websocket use connection, correct me. Maybe websocket uses connection only for handshake and then free it and return to the pool... If someone has a good proof for this mechanism I'll be kindly grateful.
(connection pool for my tomcat - s3p0)

Comment: What connection pool?

Comment: @EJP connection pool for my tomcat - s3p0

Comment: No idea what you're talking about. Connection pools are maintained at clients. Are you referring to a JDBC connection pool for example? which has exactly nothing to do with Web Sockets whatsoever.

Comment: @EJP we can set a limit for active connections client to our server, for example 200 http connection. If all 200 connections are active now a new connection will wait for fisrt free. But REST http request get connection, open it and close, then return to pool and this connection is available for new work. Websocket case: we send handshake (http request as I know), get connection from pool switch it to websocket and not return to pool, keep opened.